# Return values as keys in a new array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a PHP array.

```
array
  0 => int 1
  1 => int 13
  2 => int 16
  3 => int 17
  4 => int 18
```

What I want returned is a new array like this:

```
array(1, 13, 16, 17, 18)
```

ie. The values are now keys of a new array

I've tried `array_flip`, but I need to drop the values.
I've googled around and there doesn't seem to anything that relates.

If someone could point me to the right direction or provide a better solution, it would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

`array_flip` returns:

```
array
  1 => int 0
  13 => int 1
  16 => int 2
  17 => int 3
  18 => int 4
```

What I want is just: `array(1, 13, 16, 17, 18)`.

Am I understanding this wrong? Does the output I want actually have null values on each key?

Comment: The two arrays you posted are identical. And an array always has values, so what does "drop the values" mean?

Comment: Hm, never seen an array with no values ! maybe you mean `null` or some default other value. please update, because it does not make sense

Comment: I would love to help, but I don't understand what you need.

Comment: Could you describe a little more about why array_flip won't do the job? Where is this array going?

Comment: even if you are to accomplish a `keyless` array, how then, are you going to get any value that's inside your `keyless` array?

Comment: `$array = array(1, 13, 16, 17, 18); print_r($array);`
you will see `array(0 => 1, 1 => 13, 2 => 16...`

Comment: For completeness, even though your problem is already solved: the thing you were trying to accomplish can be done with [`array_values(...)`](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to not understand how arrays work. Every array that contains at least one value always has a key(s) and a value(s). In the case of this:

```
array(1, 13, 16, 17, 18)
```

the values are 1,13,16,... and the keys are implicitly set by PHP. In this case the value 1 has a key 0, value 13 has a key 1 and so on.

The only difference between your first and second array is that in the first you have keys defined explicitly. In short, the arrays are identical.

Comment: You're right. I just re-examined my code and it does exactly what you said. My problem lies in another area. Thank you for making me see that now.

Comment: If my answer answered your question you should accept it (click on the green icon next to the answer). Cheers!

Comment: I just had to wait for SO to let me accept it. =) Thanks, again.

Answer (score -2):

you can do a associative array:

```
$hello_im_the_new_array=Array();
foreach $array_with_keys as $im_a_key_to_other_array {
         $hello_im_the_new_array[$im_a_key_to_other_array]=$im_the_content_of_that_key_in_the_new_array
}
```

or if you are looking for read the values of other array :

```
foreach $array_with_keys as $im_a_key_to_other_array {
    echo $the_array_with_values[$im_a_key_to_other_array];
}
```

if you aren't looking for this... I don't understand your question